# I'm using react-native-splashscreen, can not understand with Installation (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

I am using [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/remobile/react-native-splashscreen), I can not understand with the part of Installation (Android)

where should I put

```
include ':react-native-splashscreen'
project(':react-native-splashscreen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@remobile/react-native-splashscreen/android')
```

in android/app/build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It should be written in `android/settings.gradle` instead of `android/app/build.gradle`.